# Flash of unstyled text when switching fonts on a loaded page

Tags: javascript, html, webfonts

I'm working on little side project that will allow users to input text and randomly generate different fonts for their inputted text. Here is a work-in-progress [demo](https://fontspark-beta.netlify.com/).

Currently, my method of loading in different fonts, is that when the user clicks the "Generate" button, a font is chosen and its Google Fonts or Typekit css embed code is set as the href of a link in my html.

Html:

```
<link id="current-font" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('current-font').href = generatedFont.src;
```

The problem I'm running into is that, sometimes there is flash of unstyled text before the generated font is loaded. It seems to be worse with the Typekit fonts. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this case of FOUC? Or if there are any recommendations of a better way to load in the fonts, I'm open.

Comment: Can you add an event listener for `load` and apply the font there?

Comment: I don't have the problem you describe. Maybe I'm on a faster internet connection?

Comment: @Cagy79 Yeah, its usually not an issue on a decent internet connection. I primarily found the issue when testing it on my phone

Comment: @Phix I'll look into that. I believe the problem is that after the Typekit css file is loaded, it then has a src url to load the font and I think the issue is with that src url in the css so I'm not sure how to check if that has been loaded

Comment: Looks like they both have an API, it may be better to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
You can add `font-display:swap` to your `@font-face`, what it does is,
 it makes sure that even though the font is not loaded yet, it will still show the text with default system-font and will as soon as the font is loaded show the real font.
 This is actually recommended by google lighthouse as well.

This will remove the flashing ( invisible text to visible ) although the style of the font will still flash ( default font style to new font style ).

**Option 2**
If you want to solve the flashing completely, load all @font-faces and attach the font-family to some elements that is not hidden as in `display:none`

This however is not as performance friendly.